# Android customly created xml button is not showing up in preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have created a button with custom attributes (actually a linear layout, which has an ImageView and a TextView, and functions like a button). **The problem is that when I try to implement this custom button in the xml layout definiton for an acitivty, it isn't displayed**. How can I fix this?

***FacebookCustomButton***

```
package com.android.neuron.custombuttons;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FacebookCustomButton extends LinearLayout {
    private Context context;

    private ImageView iconView;
    private TextView textView;

    private String iconPath;
    private Drawable iconResource;
    private String textSource;

    private int iconWidth;
    private int iconHeight;
    private int iconGravity = 0x11; //Gravity.CENTER
    private int iconMarginStart;
    private int iconMarginEnd;
    private int iconMarginTop;
    private int iconMarginBottom;

    private int textGravity = 0x11; //center
    private int textSize;
    private int textColor;



    public FacebookCustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        initializeButton();
    }

    public FacebookCustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initAttrs(context, attrs);

        initializeButton();
    }

    public FacebookCustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initAttrs(context, attrs);

        initializeButton();
    }

    void initAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if(attrs!=null) {
            TypedArray attributeArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton);

            iconResource = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_icon_resource);

            String text = attributeArray.getString(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_text_source);
            if(text==null) { //no fb textView attribuute
                text = attributeArray.getString(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_android_text);
            }
            textSource = text;

            iconWidth = (int) attributeArray.getDimension(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_icon_width, Constants.fbButton_icon_default_width);
            iconHeight = (int) attributeArray.getDimension(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_icon_height, Constants.fbButton_icon_default_height);
            iconGravity = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_icon_gravity, Constants.fbButton_icon_default_gravity);

            iconMarginStart = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_icon_marginStart, Constants.fbButton_icon_default_margin_start);
            iconMarginEnd = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_icon_marginEnd, Constants.fbButton_icon_default_margin_end);
            iconMarginTop = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_icon_marginTop, Constants.fbButton_icon_default_margin_top);
            iconMarginBottom = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_icon_marginBottom, Constants.fbButton_icon_default_margin_bottom);

            textGravity = attributeArray.getInt(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_text_gravity, Constants.fbButton_icon_default_gravity);
            textSize = (int) attributeArray.getDimension(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_text_size, Constants.fbButton_text_size);

            String textFontFamily = attributeArray.getString(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_text_font);
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), textFontFamily);
            textView.setTypeface(font);

            textColor = attributeArray.getColor(R.styleable.FacebookCustomButton_text_color, getResources().getColor(R.color.fb_defaultColor));

        }
    }

    /**
     * Initalizes the button:
     *   - the container (linear layout)
     *   - the iconView view
     *   - the textView view
     */
    private void initializeButton() {
        initializeButtonContainer();
        iconView = initializeIconView();
        textView = initializeTextView();
    }

    private void initializeButtonContainer() {
        this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        if(this.getLayoutParams() == null) {
            LayoutParams containerParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Constants.fbButton_default_height);

            containerParams.setMargins(Constants.fbButton_default_margin_start,
                    Constants.fbButton_default_margin_top,
                    Constants.fbButton_default_margin_end,
                    Constants.fbButton_default_margin_bottom);

            this.setLayoutParams(containerParams);
        }

        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        this.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.background_facebook_sign_up_button));
    }

    private TextView initializeTextView() {
        if(textSource == null) {
            textSource = context.getResources().getString(R.string.fbButton_default_text_source);
        }

        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(textSource);

        textView.setGravity(textGravity);
        textView.setTextColor(textColor);
        textView.setTextSize(textSize);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        /*
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), Constants.default_font_path);
        textView.setTypeface(font);
        */

        return textView;
    }

    private ImageView initializeIconView() {
        if(iconResource != null) {
            ImageView iconView = new ImageView(context);
            iconView.setImageDrawable(iconResource);

            LayoutParams iconViewParams = new LayoutParams(iconWidth, iconHeight);
            iconViewParams.gravity = iconGravity;
            iconViewParams.setMarginStart(iconMarginStart);
            iconViewParams.setMarginEnd(iconMarginEnd);

            iconView.setLayoutParams(iconViewParams);

            return iconView;
        } else {
            System.out.println("[Neuron.custombuttons.FCB]: Error getting iconView resource! Reutnring null.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

***attrs.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="FacebookCustomButton">
        <!-- Default Android attrs -->
        <attr name="android:enabled" />
        <attr name="android:text" />
        <attr name="android:textSize" />
        <attr name="android:textAllCaps" />
        <attr name="android:textStyle" />
        <attr name="android:fontFamily" />

        <attr name="icon_width" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="icon_height" format="dimension"/>

        <attr name="icon_gravity" format="enum">
            <enum name="top" value="0x30" />
            <enum name="bottom" value="0x50" />
            <enum name="left" value="0x03" />
            <enum name="right" value="0x05" />
            <enum name="center_vertical" value="0x10" />
            <enum name="fill_vertical" value="0x70" />
            <enum name="center_horizontal" value="0x01" />
            <enum name="fill_horizontal" value="0x07" />
            <enum name="center" value="0x11" />
            <enum name="fill" value="0x77" />
            <enum name="clip_vertical" value="0x80" />
            <enum name="clip_horizontal" value="0x08" />
            <enum name="start" value="0x00800003" />
            <enum name="end" value="0x00800005" />
        </attr>

        <attr name="icon_resource" format="integer"/>

        <attr name="icon_marginStart" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="icon_marginEnd" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="icon_marginTop" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="icon_marginBottom" format="dimension"/>

        <attr name="text_source" format="string"/>

        <attr name="text_gravity" format="enum">
            <enum name="top" value="0x30" />
            <enum name="bottom" value="0x50" />
            <enum name="left" value="0x03" />
            <enum name="right" value="0x05" />
            <enum name="center_vertical" value="0x10" />
            <enum name="fill_vertical" value="0x70" />
            <enum name="center_horizontal" value="0x01" />
            <enum name="fill_horizontal" value="0x07" />
            <enum name="center" value="0x11" />
            <enum name="fill" value="0x77" />
            <enum name="clip_vertical" value="0x80" />
            <enum name="clip_horizontal" value="0x08" />
            <enum name="start" value="0x00800003" />
            <enum name="end" value="0x00800005" />
        </attr>

        <attr name="text_size" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="text_font" format="string"/>
        <attr name="text_color" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

***Implementation in RegisterActivity:***

```
<com.android.neuron.custombuttons.FacebookCustomButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:text_source="@string/facebook_signup_button_text"
                app:text_size="14sp"
                app:text_color="@color/white"
                app:text_font="@font/roboto_medium"
                app:text_gravity="center"
                app:icon_resource="@drawable/ic_fb_white"
                app:icon_gravity="center"
                app:icon_height="24dp"
                app:icon_width="24dp"
                app:icon_marginBottom="0dp"
                app:icon_marginEnd="42dp"
                app:icon_marginStart="8dp"
                app:icon_marginTop="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only loading the `LinearLayout`. You are not adding the child views you created to your parent `LinearLayout`. Try this

```
private void initializeButton() {
        initializeButtonContainer();
        iconView = initializeIconView();
        textView = initializeTextView();
        this.addView(iconView);
        this.addView(textView); 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly the elements are still not showing up on preview (ie where you can see your activity layout in android studio), but during runtime, it works like a charm!

Comment: Yes custom view won't load up in preview. If this helped you, you can accept this as answer.